# How can I write a haskell function that applies a function on a list until one of its parameters turns 0?

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I have to write the following haskell function:

> It receives an Integer (let's call it `h`) and a list of Integers as
> parameters. It should iterate through the list, and increment the
> value of each element that is divisible by 2. Whenever it does this,
> it decrements the value of `h` by 1. It should repeat this process
> until `h` is 0. If it reaches the end of the list and the value of `h`
> is not zero, it should start the whole process all over again, until
> it does become 0. It should also work on infinite lists.  In the
> following test case:  `inc_until 4 [1,2,3,4,5]` it should return
> `[1,4,3,6,5]`

I'm not allowed to use anything besides guards, pattern matching, and helper functions I have written myself.

```
inc_until :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
inc_until _ [] = []
inc_until h (x:xs)
 | x `mod` 2 == 0 = (x+1) : inc_until (h-1) xs
 | otherwise = inc_until h xs
```

This only iterates through the list once, so it stops even when the value of h is not zero.

Comment: As for your actual question, you may want to change the result type to a tuple of the altered list and the new `h` value: `([Integer], Integer)` then you can write a second loop that applies `inc_until` repeatedly and passes the resulting `h` back into it as input.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it was a mistake.  I could use a tuple, however I have to upload it to an automated evaluation system which only accepts outputs as the exercise explains.

Comment: Uh... this spec is a little suspicious. I wonder whether your instructor actually solved this and tested it. Surely after incrementing all the even values, there are none left; so "start the process all over again" looks like it leads to an infinite loop (at least to me).

Comment: Part of our graded assignment,  haven't been able to solve it for 4 hours- The actual spec is even less specific: The function should distribute the value of h evenly among the values that are divisible by 2 of the Integer list it receives as a parameter.

Comment: "distribute the value of h evenly" isn't at all the same problem; and you can distribute evenly with only two passes (presuming the list is not actually infinite -- your answers are inconsistent on that). First pass: count how many evens there are; divide that count into `h`, to tell how much to increment each; second pass: apply the increment to each. (It'll need some fiddling to cover where `h` is not exactly divisible by the count.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Analysis** We have three scenarios to cope with:

- The list is infinite -- we assume has infinitely many evens, though not necessarily equally spaced: then we can only increment the first `h` of them (by `+1` each), and return the tail untouched/not incremented. So decrementing the `h` as we go avoids running down the list for ever.
- The list is finite, but has at least `h` many evens; treat this same as the first case: increment the first `h` evens, return the tail untouched/not incremented.
- The list is finite, and has strictly fewer than `h` evens: now it needs "distribute the value of `h` evenly", see below ...

**Deviant scenarios** [added in later edit]

- The list is infinite but contains no evens, or fewer than `h` many evens. This condition is not detectable in finite time/space, so the code here will run for ever/until resources are exhausted.
- The list is finite but contains *no* evens. The code here will return the list unchanged. Arguably this should be an error condition.

**First pass**

- Count the number of evens; also decrement `h` for each one;
- Stop and return the count if either `h` declines to zero; or end of list.

**Second pass** (This is the messy part.)

- Iterate over the original list, incrementing the evens by a rounded-up increment, and decrementing both `h` by that increment, and the count by `-1`;
- At each even, divide the `h` by the count and round up to give the increment for this element;
- (the evens in the beginning of the list are to be incremented by this rounded-up amount, until we've got only enough of `h` left over to increment the rest by a rounded-down value)
- when the decrementing `h` falls to be exactly divisible by the decrementing count, then increment the remaining evens by that exact quotient (which'll be `1` less than the rounded-up at the beginning).

examples

- `inc_until 5 [1,2,3,4,5]` (count `2` evens) ==> `[1,5,3,6,5]`
- `take 17 $ inc_until 5 [1,2 ..]` ==> `[1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9,11,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]`

  - (infinite input ==> infinite output, truncated for display)

```
module Inc_until  where

    inc_until :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
    inc_until    h      xss    = go h xss 0
      where
        go :: Int -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
        go    0      _xss     c    = go2 h xss c      -- exhausted h  
        go    _h     []       c    = go2 h xss c      -- end of list,
                                                      -- didn't exhaust h
        go    h      (x:xs)   c    | even x    = go (h - 1) xs (c + 1)
                                   | otherwise = go  h      xs  c
        
        go2 :: Int -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
        go2    0      xss      _    = xss        -- exhausted h
        go2    h      []       _    = []         -- shouldn't get here
        go2    h      xss      0    = xss        -- shouldn't get here either
        go2    h     (x:xs)    c    | even x    = let q = floor (fromIntegral h / fromIntegral c + 0.5) 
                                                  in  (x + q) : go2 (h - q) xs (c - 1)
                                    | otherwise =      x      : go2  h      xs  c
```

**Notes**

- For the first two scenarios, it would be fine to follow Daniel's approach of accumulating the incremented front of the list in reverse order; and return that if `h` got exhausted;

  - but since we have `go2` anyway, the rounded quotient for (say) `3 / 3` comes out right as `1`, we can avoid creating the temp list.
- IMO the code is cleaner if pass 1 merely accum's the count of evens. [YMMV]
- To get the count of evens, we can't merely filter/fold over the list: it might be infinite/there might be more than `h` many evens.
- In testing, I found the `round` function was occasionally giving out-by-1 errors; hence the ugly business with `floor`. Of course it's arbitrary whether you round up at the beginning vs. round down at the beginning until you've enough remainder to round up the trailing elements.

**Afterthoughts**

Heh heh even this short exercise shows how code changes as you explore what's left unsaid in the spec/typically bump into deviant/unanticipated scenarios -- and the code builds up a 'legacy' of sub-optimal (but not sufficiently bad to fix) cruft. Examples:

- I was at first worried about the messiness of rounding up the quotient at the start of "distribute the value of `h` evenly"; then rounding down later.
- But the `floor ( ... / ... + 0.5)` expression does the appropriate rounding automatically.
- I at first coded `go` using the prefix accumulator per Daniel's answer -- so the `go 0 ...` equation (`h` exhausted) would return immediately; and accumulating the count in parallel -- which is why `go` has an over-complex accumulating logic.
- I then realised if count reaches same as `h` the quotient and rounding logic would work just as well for say `3 / 3`, so also called `go2` and stripped out the accumulating prefix logic.
- But that results in `go` merely counting the number of evens (or `h`, whichever is the smaller) -- in which case carrying the count down the recursive descent is over-complex. Instead it could be:

```
    inc_until    h      xss    = go2 h xss (count_evens h xss) 
      where
        count_evens :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
        count_evens    0      _xss   = 0
        count_evens    _h     []     = 0
        count_evens    h      (x:xs) | even x    = 1 + count_evens (h - 1) xs
                                     | otherwise =     count_evens  h      xs

      -- go2 as above
```

- BTW I'm not criticising Daniel's solution: it's perfectly workable for the problem as originally stated. The "distribute the value of h evenly" requirement didn't appear until after Daniel posted that solution, and still it's only in a comment. Something like that wholly upending the 'spec' should be in the main question.

Comment: (Why was this downvoted?) I think this might be the closest we can get to the spec. I think, however, that `inc_until 5 [3,3,3,...]` gets stuck in infinite recursion at  `| otherwise = go  h      xs  c`.

Comment: Another deviant case is a finite list containing only odd nums. The code given here just returns the list unchanged (the `go2` line with comment `shouldn't get here either`). Other design choices are possible -- like throwing an error.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your implementation compared to the spec.

1. You don't stop when `h` is 0. You can easily fix this by adding an explicit clause for that case.

   ```
   inc_until 0 xs = {- ... -}
   ```
2. You don't start over when `h` is too big. Here I find the spec a little ambiguous: should you start over with the modified list, or the original one? Anyway, one way forward would be to implement a helper function that iterates through the list at most once, returning not just the updated list, but also the updated value of `h`.

   ```
   inc_until_once :: Integer -> [Integer] -> (Integer, [Integer])
   inc_until_once h xs = {- ... -}
   ```

   Then you can implement your top-level function in terms of this one, looping until `h` drops to `0`.

   ```
   inc_until h xs = case inc_until_once h xs of
       (0 , xs') -> xs'
       (h', xs') -> inc_until h' {- xs or xs' depending on what the spec means -}
   ```

   An alternate strategy that may appeal to some people would be to observe that the real problem with the `inc_until _ []` case is that we don't know what list to restart with. If the spec means to restart with the modified list, we can fix this by passing along a (reversed) prefix to toss onto the front of our answer, rather than emitting the answer directly.

   ```
   inc_until_acc prefix 0 xs = reverse prefix ++ xs
   inc_until_acc prefix h [] = {- we now know that prefix is related to the list we should restart with -}
   inc_until_acc prefix h (x:xs) = {- ... -}

   inc_until = inc_until_acc []
   ```

Comment: Further, the part of the spec "It should also work on infinite lists." baffles me. I don't think that can be achieved.

Comment: I was able to solve it this way. The infinite list part isn't exactly infinite, rather there are test cases where the input starts with "take 50" for example, and the evaluation system compares it to the expected output. Thanks so much for the help, saved me a lot of struggle!

Comment: "should you start over with the modified list?" After one pass through, the evens are incremented by 1 to odds. So the second pass won't be able to find any work to do. IOW if `h` is too big, this'll loop forever.

Comment: @chi I think infinite lists can be handled (it's messy); see my answer. (And I'm thinking Daniel's answer will go wrong with a sufficiently evil test case.)

Comment: @chi I admit to being unenlightened. What's difficult about infinite lists?

Comment: I'm probably missing something. The way I read the spec, also accounting for the given test case, on input `inc_until 2 [2,3,3,3,....]` we need to increment `2` only once if there is some other even number later on, and twice otherwise. There is no way to detect "there is some even in an infinite list", the problem is undecidable.